# Como alterar a cor das linhas de uma tabela de acordo com o valor de cada uma

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Estou com problemas para desenvolver uma function que altere a cor de uma `<tr>` baseado em um valor específico de uma `<td>`

Preciso que essa function faça para cada linha, pois elas contém valores diferentes.

A princípio os valores são "Completed, Delayed, In Progress e New" e todos os dados foram inseridos manualmente, mas logo serão carregados do banco e terão sempre os mesmo valores.

```
            <table id="allBatchesTable" style="width: 80%">

                <!-- Essa primeira linha é os nomes das colunas -->
                <tr>
                    <th>Batch ID</th>
                    <th>Product</th>
                    <th>Batch Size</th>
                    <th>Priority</th>
                    <th>Start Req</th>
                    <th>Status</th>
                </tr>

                <tr id="idTr">
                    <td id="IDbatchID">B01091</td>
                    <td id="IDproduct">Choco Milk</td>
                    <td id="IDbatchSize">30000</td>
                    <td id="IDpriority">1</td>
                    <td id="IDstartReq">03-31-2017 08:00:00</td>
```

A partir daqui preciso fazer com que a linha tenha sua cor de fundo alterada de acordo com o valor contido nesta `<td>`

```
                    <td id="IDstatus">Completed</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>B01090</td>
                    <td>Choco Milk</td>
                    <td>30000</td>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>03-30-2017 06:00:00</td>
                    <td>Delayed</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>B04551</td>
                    <td>Strawberry Milk</td>
                    <td>20000</td>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>04-01-2017 00:00:00</td>
                    <td>In Progress</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>B03225</td>
                    <td>Banana Milk</td>
                    <td>15000</td>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>04-01-2017 00:00:00</td>
                    <td>New</td>
                </tr>

            </table>
```

Eu consegui fazer essa function que altera a cor de fundo, porém o único problema é que ela agrega a cor para todas as linhas. O que eu preciso é que cada linha tenha sua cor trocada baseado no valor contido dentro da `<td>`

Completed = Verde
Delayed = Vermelho
In Progress = Amarelo
New = Branco

```
    <script>

            $(function () {
                var texto = $("#allBatchesTable tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(6)").text();
                var result = (texto);

                if (result == "Completed") {
                    $("#allBatchesTable").css("background", "#00b503");
                } else if (result == "Delayed") {
                    $("#allBatchesTable").css("background", "#f20000");
                } else if (result == "In Progress") {
                    $("#allBatchesTable").css("background", "#ffff00");
                } else if (result == "New") {
                    $("#allBatchesTable").css("background", "#ffffff");
                } else {
                    $("#allBatchesTable").css("background", "#ccc");
                }
            })

    </script>
```

Na linha  `var texto =  $("#idDaTabela tr:nth-child(2) td:nth-child(6)").text();` repare que temos `tr:nth-child(2)` que faz referencia a primeira linha da tabela e  `td:nth-child(6)` a sexta coluna dessa linha.

O único problema que não consegui uma solução foi que essa function agrega a cor a todas as `<td>`a mesma cor baseado no primeiro valor encontrado. Ela a princípio foi a única que consegui fazer com que trocasse a cor de fundo, pois as minhas anteriores não faziam nada, mesmo que eu tivesse seguido esse fluxo.

Espero ter me feito entender a dúvida que tenho.

Comment: Qual é a linguagem no servidor com que estás a gerar esse HTML?

Comment: @Sergio não entendi direito sua pergunta. Me desculpe, como assim?

Comment: Podias fazer isso no servidor quando geras esse HTML, com lógica para juntar por exemplo uma classe de CSS com a côr que queres. Esse HTML é gerado no servidor ou JavaScript?

Comment: Esse HTML é gerado pelo JavaScript. Esse HTML está sendo usado como protótipo para o próximo passo que darei, eu sou novato com desenvolvimento web e por enquanto eu tenho isso desenvolvido por mim mesmo e não tenho muita prática em estilização. Eu consigo pensar numa lógica para que funcione, mas não sei como fazer.

Comment: Ok, então podes colocar o JavaScript que gera essa tabela? Assim fica mais fácil e melhor de organizar.

Comment: @Sergio Por enquanto essa tabela foi criada manualmente, acho que não respondi direito. Eu criei a tabela manualmente, este é o código dela. Os dados delas também estão aí, não tenho nada sendo criado via script a princípio.

Comment: Ok, e queres aplicar essas cores à tabela toda ou só a essa linha que tem IDs?

Comment: @Sergio Então, eu quero que cada linha receba a cor baseada no valor encontrado na `<td>` As demais que não contém IDs é por que eu esqueci de colocar. Eu preciso que a function altere sempre automaticamente as cores de todas as linhas que possuem valor. Leve em conta que eu posso nesse momento inserir um valor diferente e gostaria que a function funcionasse e alterasse pra cor adequada, conforme eu especifiquei acima.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes fazer isso com dados estruturados, com um JSON por exemplo assim:

```js
var tabela = {
  colunas: ["Batch ID", "Product", "Batch Size", "Priority", "Start Req", "Status"],
  linhas: [
    ["B01091", "Choco Milk", 30000, 1, "03-31-2017 08:00:00", "Completed"],
    ["B01090", "Choco Milk", 30000, 1, "03-30-2017 06:00:00", "Delayed"],
    ["B04551", "Strawberry Milk", 20000, 2, "04-01-2017 00:00:00", "In Progress"],
    ["B03225", "Banana Milk", 15000, 3, "04-01-2017 00:00:00", "New"]
  ]
}
```

E depois gerar a tabela e colocar essas classes ou cores que precisas:

```js
var tabela = {
  "colunas": ["Batch ID", "Product", "Batch Size", "Priority", "Start Req", "Status"],
  "linhas": [
    ["B01091", "Choco Milk", 30000, 1, "03-31-2017 08:00:00", "Completed"],
    ["B01090", "Choco Milk", 30000, 1, "03-30-2017 06:00:00", "Delayed"],
    ["B04551", "Strawberry Milk", 20000, 2, "04-01-2017 00:00:00", "In Progress"],
    ["B03225", "Banana Milk", 15000, 3, "04-01-2017 00:00:00", "New"]
  ],
  "cores": {
    "Completed": "#ada",
    "Delayed": "#daa",
    "In Progress": "#add",
    "New": "#fff"
  }
}

var table = document.querySelector('table');
var head = table.querySelector('thead');
var body = table.querySelector('tbody');

// adicionar colunas
var cols = document.createElement('tr');
head.appendChild(cols);
tabela.colunas.forEach(function(col) {
  var th = document.createElement('th');
  th.innerHTML = col;
  cols.appendChild(th);
});

// adicionar linhas
tabela.linhas.forEach(function(linha) {
  var tr = document.createElement('tr');
  linha.forEach(function(col) {
    var td = document.createElement('td');
    td.innerHTML = col;
    if (tabela.cores[col]) tr.style.backgroundColor = tabela.cores[col];
    tr.appendChild(td);
  });
  body.appendChild(tr);
});
```

```html
<table>
  <thead></thead>
  <tbody></tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Obrigado @Sergio. Me ajudou muito e agora vou conseguir melhorar meu código com as suas dicas. Muito obrigado!

Comment: @MatheusAlvesdeOliveira de nada! Podes fazer isso também com classes de CSS. Mas com este exemplo já fica mais fácil adaptar.